# Kotlin Sort two lists by one item

Tags: arrays, sorting, kotlin

[![enter image description here][1]][1]How can I sort locales and visitantes per minute if I am using sealed class

The Model

```
sealed class Item {
    class ItemOne(var idJugador: String = "", var nombre: String = "", var minuto: String = "", var tarjeta: String) : Item()

    class ItemTwo(var idJugador: String = "", var nombre: String = "", var minuto: String = "", var tarjeta: String) : Item()
}
```

This is Adapter

```
    class DetallesAdapter(
        private val locales: ArrayList<Item>? = ArrayList(),
        private val visitantes: ArrayList<Item>? = ArrayList()
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

        //val itemTotal = ArrayList<Item.ItemOne>().sortedBy {it.minuto} + ArrayList<Item.ItemTwo>().sortedBy {it.minuto}

        val itemTotal = locales!! + visitantes!!

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = itemTotal.size
........
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `minuto` property in `Item` class and then just use `sortedBy`:

```
sealed class Item {
    abstract var minuto: String

    class ItemOne(var idJugador: String = "", var nombre: String = "", override var minuto: String = "", var tarjeta: String) : Item()

    class ItemTwo(var idJugador: String = "", var nombre: String = "", override var minuto: String = "", var tarjeta: String) : Item()
}

...

val itemTotal = (locales!! + visitantes!!).sortedBy { it.minuto }
```

Comment: val itemTotal = (locales!! + visitantes!!).sortedBy { it.minuto } This line not found.

Comment: sorry, it's not clear to me what you mean. You have to change your `Item` class and then change `val itemTotal = locales!! + visitantes!!` to `val itemTotal = (locales!! + visitantes!!).sortedBy { it.minuto }`

Comment: I have it the same as the answer you sent me, but after minute 76 is minute 44 - 48 - 54 ... and I want you to order everything, that's what I mean. Thank you

Comment: It is correct, but what happens is that kotlin the minutes that are of a digit add a 0 to the right.
For example minute 6 kotlin sees it as minute 60. Any solution?

Comment: 34 - 6 - 78 not

Comment: It this case you can use `toInt()` function: https://pl.kotl.in/FXPV7Ha6J

Comment: In my case I receive the minutes with special characters * "minuto": "(23')" *  how can I pass it to Int?

Comment: you can leave the only number with `isDigit` https://pl.kotl.in/s6pIFjwe5

Answer (score 0):

```
    class DetallesAdapter(
    private val locales: List<Item> = ArrayList(),
    private val visitantes: List<Item> = ArrayList()
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    var context: Context? = null

    val itemTotal = (locales!! + visitantes!!).sortedBy { it.minuto }



    // get the size of the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = itemTotal.size
............
}


    sealed class Item {

    abstract var minuto: String

    class GolLocal(var idJugador: String = "", var nombre: String = "",
                   override var minuto: String = "", var tarjeta: String) : Item()

    class GolVisi(var idJugador: String = "", var nombre: String = "",
                  override var minuto: String = "", var tarjeta: String) : Item()
}
```